# Different behavior on UITableView control

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

There Is this control that I really appreciate: [github link](https://github.com/gasparenovara/ExpandableRows) the problem is that now I have a situation where when I need to open one row and all the previous ones should close, I can only have one open row at the time.

Since I'm not very experienced with xcode, I need some info on where should I start and the necessary steps to make the code work the way I need right now.

I managed to make some tests but not a viable solution, here is what I have right now:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    NSInteger row = indexPath.row;

    if (indexPath.section == 0) {

        NSLog(@"indexPath1 = %i", selectedRow);

        NSDictionary *d = [self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

            NSUInteger count = indexPath.row +1;
            NSMutableArray *arCells = [NSMutableArray array];

            for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                [self.firstForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
            }

            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Leave Element:::%@ %@|",[d valueForKey:@"name"],[d valueForKey:@"book"]);
        }

        if (selectedRow == row) {
            NSLog(@"selectedRow2 = %i",selectedRow);

            NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

            if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
                NSArray *ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

                [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];
            }

            selectedRow = -1;
            return;
        }

        if (selectedRow >= 0) {
            NSLog(@"selectedRow3 = %i",selectedRow);

            NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:selectedRow];

            if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
                NSArray *ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];

                [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];
            }

            selectedRow = row;
        }

        selectedRow = row;
        [tableView beginUpdates]; [tableView endUpdates];
    }


    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        NSDictionary *d = [self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
            NSArray *ar = [d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
            BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

            for (NSDictionary *dInner in ar) {
                NSInteger index = [self.secondForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];

                isAlreadyInserted = (index > 0 && index != NSIntegerMax);
                if (isAlreadyInserted) break;
            }

            if (isAlreadyInserted) {
                [self miniMizeSecondsRows:ar];
            }
            else {
                NSUInteger count = indexPath.row+1;
                NSMutableArray *arCells = [NSMutableArray array];

                for (NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                    [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:1]];
                    [self.secondForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                }

                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
            }
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"Leave Element:::%@ %@|",[d valueForKey:@"name"],[d valueForKey:@"book"]);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What is the way you need? It is not clear to me what your goal is...

Comment: In the current github control you are free to open has many rows you like and they will stay open, what I need is to limit the tableview to open just 1 row at the time. If I open one row, any other rows that maybe open, must close automatically :)

Comment: '[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];' are you using this line in order to deselect previous opened row? If not where is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATED**: [Expandable Rows JSON](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3zj2ftcccwi2xxu/ExpandableRows-master%20JSON.zip?dl=0) is your project, with auto-collapse working for all rows.

Also check [Expandable Rows](https://github.com/bouzikas/ExpandableRows), i forked this project to help Novara and improve it. Now working for all  sections, except nested rows.

**FIRST STEP**

Track opened row for each section. Of course this can be done using `NSArray` of tabOpened for multiple sections.

```
@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController {
    NSInteger tabOpened_1;
    NSInteger tabOpened_2;
}
```

**SECOND STEP**

Next initialize those with "-1" value, for none opened tab.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    ........

    [self.firstForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.firstArray];
    tabOpened_1 = -1;
    [self.secondForTable addObjectsFromArray:self.secondArray];
    tabOpened_2 = -1;
}
```

**THIRD STEP**

Change the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

        if (indexPath.section==0) {
            NSDictionary *d=[self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if([d valueForKey:@"produtos"]) {
                if (tabOpened_1 == -1) {
                    NSLog(@"No tab opened in first section");
                    tabOpened_1 = indexPath.row;
                } else if(tabOpened_1 != indexPath.row && tabOpened_1 > indexPath.row){
                    NSDictionary *d_ = [self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:tabOpened_1];
                    NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                    [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar_];
                    tabOpened_1 = indexPath.row;
                }

                NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

                for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
                    NSInteger index=[self.firstForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
                    isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                    if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
                }

                if(isAlreadyInserted) {
                    [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar];
                } else {
                    NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
                    NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                        [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
                        [self.firstForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                    }
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                }

                if (tabOpened_1 == -1) {
                    NSLog(@"No tab opened in first section");
                    tabOpened_1 = indexPath.row;
                } else if(tabOpened_1 != indexPath.row && tabOpened_1 < indexPath.row){
                    NSDictionary *d_ = [self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:tabOpened_1];
                    NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                    [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar_];
                    tabOpened_1 = indexPath.row - [ar_ count];
                    tabOpened_1 = (tabOpened_1 < 0) ? indexPath.row : tabOpened_1;
                }
            } else {
               NSLog(@"Leave Element:::%@ %@|",[d valueForKey:@"nome"],[d valueForKey:@"numeroConta"]);
            }
            for (int i=0; i < [[self.rowsPerSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *d_ = [self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:i];
                NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                [self miniMizeSecondsRows:ar_];
            }
        }

        if (indexPath.section==1) {
            if (tabOpened_2 == -1) {
                NSLog(@"No tab opened in second section");
                tabOpened_2 = indexPath.row;
            } else if(tabOpened_2 != indexPath.row && tabOpened_2 > indexPath.row){
                NSDictionary *d_ = [self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:tabOpened_2];
                NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                [self miniMizeSecondsRows:ar_];
                tabOpened_2 = indexPath.row;
            }

            NSDictionary *d=[self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            if([d valueForKey:@"produtos"]) {
                NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"produtos"];

                BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;

                for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
                    NSInteger index=[self.secondForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
                    isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
                    if(isAlreadyInserted) break;
                }

                if(isAlreadyInserted) {
                    [self miniMizeSecondsRows:ar];
                } else {

                    NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
                    NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
                    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
                        [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:1]];
                        [self.secondForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
                    }
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
                }

                if (tabOpened_2 == -1) {
                    NSLog(@"No tab opened in second section");
                    tabOpened_2 = indexPath.row;
                } else if(tabOpened_2 != indexPath.row && tabOpened_2 < indexPath.row){
                    NSDictionary *d_ = [self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:tabOpened_2];
                    NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                    [self miniMizeSecondsRows:ar_];
                    tabOpened_2 = indexPath.row - [ar_ count];
                    tabOpened_2 = (tabOpened_2 < 0) ? indexPath.row : tabOpened_2;
                }
            } else {
                //NSLog(@"Leave Element:::%@ %@|",[d valueForKey:@"nome"],[d valueForKey:@"book"]);
            }

            for (int i=0; i < [[self.rowsPerSection objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] integerValue]; i++) {
                NSDictionary *d_ = [self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:i];
                NSArray *ar_ = [d_ valueForKey:@"produtos"];
                [self miniMizeFirstsRows:ar_];
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I have a question, in these lines: NSDictionary *d_ = [self.firstForTable objectAtIndex:3]; and NSDictionary *d_ = [self.secondForTable objectAtIndex:0]; why the values 3 and 0?

Comment: Because when this code is executed, the index 3 of firstForTable/secondForTable is the row which we want to collapse. Respectively for value 0, because any of the rows is clicked above first, always we want to collapse the first row. In fact this is not the right way, but its a guidance to help you on how you can do it and work for you.

Comment: Sorry to bother you with another question but I'm also in the process of learning :) I'm trying to use this code with the following parsed JSON: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30471368/gb.json I'm using your code but the tableview isn't openning one row at the time. Can you give me some tips on how to adapt the code? Again I'm sorry to bother you with such questions.

Comment: Its ok, can you show me the tableView which resulting through this json? As i told you this solution fits only with this table. I'm currently working on this to support multiple rows in each section

Comment: Thanks :) sure, I duplicated your current project and made some changes to show the parsed JSON code. It shows the correct rows and when you expand the row it shows the correct number of children, no text. Here is the project: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/30471368/ExpandableRows-master%20JSON.zip

Comment: I think the json that you use its not in the correct form, and thats why child rows didn't have any text.

Comment: The problem is that you have use `descricao` instead of `nome` as a key for text of child rows.

Comment: Yes I know thanks :) but what do you think I need to change so that I can make the code work with this particular JSON on the matter of openning one row at the time. Thanks for the support so far.

Answer (score 5):

Is this really necessary for you to use mentioned by you control? If not I can propose you another control.

It is open source and available on github https://github.com/Augustyniak/RATreeView.
RATreeView was written by me and (from what you wrote) it has functionality you need. Its public API is based on UITableView's one so it is really simple to use. It has pretty expanded documentation which will allow you to get all needed information. Linked github's repository contains sample project which shows exactly how to start using it in your own project.

In case you start to use it and have some questions just ask.